# How to handle dependant multi module Maven projects in Teamcity

Tags: maven, teamcity

We have Java projects *A*, *B* and *C*, all with large code base and many modules, built using Maven. *B* depends on *A*, and *C* depends on *A* and *B*, for development snapshot dependencies are used. We use something like git flow, and for any feature there can be a branch in all three projects. I want to setup `verify` and `package` builds in Teamcity so that each build in *B* and *C* uses snapshots from the corresponding branches in different projects.

The only solution I coukd come up with is simply setup snapshot dependencies on `install` builds and run them on the same agent, so that Maven resolves snapshots to the needed version. But this approach clogs up Maven caches and requires rebuilding everything every time. Is there may be something more simple and effective?

Comment: That sounds like you need to have a multi module build instead of separated project which would solve that in one go...

Comment: @khmarbaise you mean adding three VCS roots and building all at once? This doesn't solve the redundancy problem, only messes it up since projects are used separately in other builds

Comment: No make those modules into a single git repository / same trunk (svn) and build them ....